# Dart/Flutter problems with clean code when using async/await

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await

I am in the process of learning Dart/Flutter by developing a small Android app. While I try to understand how async and await works in Dart/Flutter, I often find myself struggling when trying to use it and write clean code. Here is a shortened example:

```
// ...

void main() {
  runApp(const RootWidget());
}

class RootWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const RootWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      // ...
      home: CameraWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class CameraWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  late final CameraDescription camera;

  CameraWidget({super.key}) {
    final cameras = await availableCameras(); // <-- ERROR
    camera = cameras.first;
  }

  // ...
}
```

As you can see in the example, I need to call an asynchronous function from inside a constructor, which is not allowed and produces an error. I researched how I can circumvent this problem and found 2 possible solutions, but none of those solutions really work here:

**Factory**

One suggested solution is to use a factory function which creates an instance of the CameraWidget class. But there is a problem in doing so, the factory function itself also needs to be marked async, because it needs to use await to wait for the returned List of availableCameras. This factory method then must be used instead of the regular constructor inside the build function of RootWidget, which would also turn the build function into an asynchronous function. But this is not possible because we can't change the function signature of the build function.

**then**

Another solution I found, was to use the *then* function like so:

```
CameraWidget({super.key}) {
  availableCameras().then((cameras) {
    camera = cameras.first;
  });
}
```

But this does not block execution and the camera instance variable is not set before it should be used.

---

The only working solution I found, is to get the CameraDescription in the main function, give it to the constructor of the RootWidget, which also gives it to the constructor of the CameraWidget.

But this is a really dirty solution, because then the code which initializes the camera instance variable is inside the main function, where it doesn't belong. IMHO the code to initialize the camera instance variable belongs inside the constructor of CameraWidget. I mean, this is basically what constructors are for, right?

This is not the first time I had such a problem with async/await in Dart/Flutter, where I needed the value of an asynchronous function A inside another function B, but I couldn't mark the function B asynchronous and I had to work around that. Which is really annoying, because I just want the return value of one function call and I need to put a lot of extra steps in to get it to the place I need it, just because it is asynchronous.

What am I doing wrong in regards to async/await, and what would be a cleaner solution to the example given?

Comment: Use a [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html).